# How to connect SpringBoot (on Wildfly) to MySQL on openshift 3?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

To put a SpringBoot application on openshift 3 the suggested route is by using the s2i of Wildfly. For the moment this is sufficient for me.

How can I conect SpringBoot (on Wildfly) to MySQL at openshift 3?

Please show how I can use environment variables and/ linking.

Do I need to prepare the maven file to produce SpringBoot as a war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free eBook at:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

Uses a Wildfly application and connects it to a database. See if that will work for your situation.

Comment: I read the chapters up till the database part. So, linking (= making the database accessible by the wildly application) is not explicitly done. The database was added to the project, that does the trick? So the docker container link parameter is not needed?

Comment: No. You are setting environment variable manually against the deployment configuration for the application so the application knows the login details for the database. There is currently no automatic population of environment variables.

Comment: For the environment settings, yes, I understand. 
In 'normal' docker I have to LINK the database container to the application container, e.g. 'mysqldb'. How do I make the database container itself known to the application container? In the standard S2I example with node.js/mongodb I see that the database container is explicitly specified via a seperate environment variable (with value 'mongodb').

Comment: Anything in the same project can already see each other, no explicit linking is required. The hostname of something else is the service name it has, which is usually the same as the name you gave the application when creating it. The service name acts as a hostname as OpenShift automatically adds a hostname entry into an internal DNS which maps to the IP address of the service.